# How to check if JSON includes something NODEJS

Tags: node.js, json

I want to check if my JSON includes "hello". All of the JSON.

Normally if it was a string I'd do this:

`var string = "hello there this is a test"`

```
if(string.includes("hello")) return console.log("Hello found")
```

is there a JSON version for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the JSON into javascript object using `JSON.parse()` and then search on it.

For example:

```
let jsonOb = {"msg": "hello there this is a test"}

let ob = JSON.parse(jsonOb)

let string = ob.msg
if(string.includes("hello")) return console.log("Hello found")
```

Hope it solves your problem.

Comment: I don't want it looking at just the "msg":
I want it to look at all of them

Comment: then you can use `for - in` here. for example : `for (var key in ob) { var string = ob[key];  if(string.includes("hello")) return console.log("Hello found") }`